# React hooks useEffect fetch CORS issue

Tags: reactjs, api, react-hooks, cors

I'm having a hard time finding information about where to place headers for CORS in this try/catch block.

e.g: mode: 'no-cors'

```
useEffect(() => {

  const fetchData = async() => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const response = await fetch('http://[::1]:3000/users');
      const json = await response.json();
      setData(json.results, setLoading(false));
    } catch(err) {
      console.warn('API Error:', err);
      setLoading(false);
    }
  }

  if(amount) {
    fetchData(amount);
  }
}, [amount])
```

I am new to hooks and would appreciate any advice or improvements on communication with a backend.

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score -1):

The fetch() method can optionally accept a second parameter, that allows you to control a number of different settings:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async() => {
            try {
                setLoading(true);
                const response = await fetch('http://[::1]:3000/users', {
                    method: 'POST', // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
                    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
                    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
                    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                    },
                    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
                    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
                    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
                });
                const json = await response.json();
                setData(json.results, setLoading(false));
            } catch(err) {
                console.warn('API Error:', err);
                setLoading(false);
            }
        };

        if(amount) {
            fetchData(amount);
        }
    }, [amount]);
```

Check the [FetchAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) documentation for more details.